# Change Listview Text Size via ActionBar Button

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have menu buttons which decrease and increase text sizes.

```
          case R.id.decrease_font :
             fontSize = generalValues.getFontSize() ;
            generalValues.setFontSize(--fontSize);
            textView.setTextSize(fontSize);

            return true;

        case R.id.increase_font :
             fontSize = generalValues.getFontSize() ;
            generalValues.setFontSize(++fontSize);

            textView.setTextSize(fontSize);
            return true;
```

GeneralValues.java

```
public Float getFontSize() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);

    String fontSize = "";
    fontSize = sharedPrefs
            .getString("prefSyncFrequency", "10f");

    return Float.parseFloat(fontSize);

}

public void setFontSize(Float fontSize) {

    if(fontSize > 35f)
        fontSize = 35f;
    if(fontSize < 10f)
        fontSize = 10f;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

    editor.putString("prefSyncFrequency", fontSize.toString());

    editor.commit();

    this.fontSize = fontSize;
}
```

But. There is a problem. When I click increase or decrease button just first row of listview is been updated.

Screenshoot is at the below link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMMIk.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is wrong? Why someones give me negative ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font size within your adapter getView() method, then it will affect to all the rows.